# Create Multi Check box filter for html with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, filter, checkbox

i have multiple articles shown in a div
the function will hide all items first
i go in each div item in the items and see if its classlist contains the filter to show

the code:

```
div class="filter">
    <h1>Select products</h1> 
        <div class="checkbox"> <label><input type="checkbox" rel="" onchange="change();" checked="checked" />ALL</label> </div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label><input type="checkbox" rel="TABLET" onchange="change();" />TABLET</label> </div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label><input type="checkbox" rel="MEDICAL" onchange="change();" />MEDICAL</label> </div>
        <div class="checkbox">  <label><input type="checkbox" rel="TISANE NATUREL" onchange="change();" />TISANE NATUREL</label> </div>
         </div>

<div id="items">
 <div class="column #MEDICAL# #TABLET#">
        <div class="content">
          <h4>XLS MEDICAL - COMPRIME [FAT REDUCER] {120}</h4>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Ref.: 4384145</p>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Barcode: 5400951001098</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column #MEDICAL# #TABLET#">
        <div class="content">
            <h4>XLS MEDICAL - COMPRIME [MAX STRENGTH] {120}</h4>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Ref.: 3214897</p>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Barcode: 5414963013147</p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column #TISANE NATUREL#">
        <div class="content">
            <h4>XLS MEDICAL - TISANE [FROID] {20}</h4>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Ref.: 3045382</p>
            <p style="color:blue">Product Barcode: 5412141225559</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
          function change() {
              let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.row > div')),
                  selectedFilters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.models:checked');

              results.forEach(function (result) { result.style.display = 'none'; });

              selectedFilters.forEach(function (filter) { 
                  results.forEach(function (item) {
                      if (Array.inArray(item.classList, filter.getAttribute('rel')) != -1) { item.style.display = 'block'; };
                  });
              });
    }

    change();
</script>
```

i have tried to change the results to ".row > content" it hides all the item without showing any

my code is not working, thanks for help.

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

some of your classes have `#`. so if you are looking for example for `MEDICAL`, the script will skip `#MEDICAL#` because of that `#`, try to remove it and try again.

or you can use this code instead:

```
function change() {
    let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.row > div')),
    selectedFilters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.models:checked');

    results.forEach(function (result) { result.style.display = 'none'; });

    selectedFilters.forEach(function (filter) { 
        results.forEach(function (item) {
            if (checkClass(filter.getAttribute('rel'), item.classList)) {
                item.style.display = 'block';
            };
        });
    });
}

function checkClass(rel, originalList) {
    let list = originalList.map((x) => {
        return x.replace("#", "");
    });
    let classes = rel.split(" ");
    for (var i = classes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (classes[i] == "") continue;
        if (!Array.inArray(list, classes[i])) {
            return false;
        };
    }
    return true;
}
```

in this example the item class list is edited first before the checking to remove all `#`, and takes the classes in `rel` check them (even if they are plural).

Comment: `Array.from()` is not necessary since NodeList already provides the prototype  forEach method

Comment: `style` should be avoided in JS unless for when really necessary. CSS classes should be used instead and Element.classList.toggle()

Comment: About `Array.from()` is not used for ndeList but for class list, it checks if the given class from rel (`classes[i]` ) is present in the item.classList ( `list` after mapping).

Comment: Have you tried to remove Array.from? Should work as well. Also, regarding your *checkClass* function... why don't you simply use [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: Also, why you support the use of `rel` tag for something `data-*` attribute should be used? For more info read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

Comment: well i agree if i did the script i would use `data-` instead of `rel` and definitely use a better classes filtering, however thank you for the informations, it's just that in my answer i tried to write the script the closest way that he wrote it himself, so he can get the solution without getting confused him with new methods like (you shouldn't use this at all, and you should do this instead), i just answers his issue no more, thank you anyway.